# Absolutely Positioned Grandchildren Of Flex Container - Firefox & MS issues

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I am trying to use flexbox on a set of divs, which works just fine. The divs are positioned properly on all browsers with the right amount of spacing.

Inside each of these divs, however, I am struggling to position some text using absolute positioning.

What I want to do on only certain images, is put a `p` tag positioned 11px below it's parent. On others, I want to position the `p` tag inside the parent.

I can position the inner text with no problem across all browsers. However, on Firefox and Edge/IE, I cannot position the outer text with the same code. I found a hack for Firefox, which you will see below using `@-moz-document url-prefix()`.

What could I be missing?

Please note, I'm not asking about children of flex containers, but grandchildren. Many of the questions I have perused on SO deal with children only. My children here are fine. It's the grandkids who have issues.

```css
.container {
    background: #969898;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 980px;
    width: 90%;
}

.flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}


.row {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.img-responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.features-section__features {
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
}

.circle-inner {
    background-color: #8FCBE8;
}

.circle-inner p {
    color: #1E2D3B;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 54px;
    margin: 35px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}

.circle-outer {
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #8FCBE8;
    position: relative;
}

.circle-outer img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 116px;
    margin: 6px auto;
    width: 116px;
}

.circle-outer p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 48px;
    left: -96px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -59px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    width: 320px;
}


/* fix for issue with absolute position on firefox */

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .circle-outer p {
        left: -96px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -80px;
    }
}

/* some media queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    .circle-outer p {
        width: 200px;
        left: -36px;
    }
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        .circle-outer p {
            left: -36px;
        }
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .circle {
        margin: 50px 40px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 470px) {
    .circle {
        margin: 50px 20px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 373px) {
    .circle:nth-child(even) {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<head>

    <!-- NORMALIZE CSS -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css'>
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,500i,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='features-section__features flex row'>
      <div class='circle circle-outer'>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people" class='img-responsive'>
          <p>This text should be below with ~ 11px margin.</p>
      </div>
      <div class='circle circle-inner'>
          <p>This text is happily set inside</p>
      </div>
      <div class='circle circle-outer'>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people" class='img-responsive'>
          <p>This text should be below with ~ 11px margin.</p>
      </div>
      <div class='circle circle-inner'>
          <p>This text is happily set inside.</p>
      </div>
      <div class='circle circle-outer'>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people" class='img-responsive'>
          <p>This text should be below with ~ 11px margin.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the outer text positioned 11px below the parent.

Instead of using `bottom: -59px`, which appears to render differently across browsers, this alternative may be more precise and efficient:

```
.circle-outer p {
    top: calc(100% + 11px);
    margin: 0; /* remove default margins */
 }
```

```css
.container {
    background: #969898;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 980px;
    width: 90%;
}

.flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}


.row {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.img-responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.features-section__features {
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
}

.circle-inner {
    background-color: #8FCBE8;
}

.circle-inner p {
    color: #1E2D3B;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 54px;
    margin: 35px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}

.circle-outer {
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #8FCBE8;
    position: relative;
}

.circle-outer img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 116px;
    margin: 6px auto;
    width: 116px;
}

.circle-outer p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 48px;
    left: -96px;
    position: absolute;
    /* bottom: -59px; */    
    top: calc(100% + 11px); /* NEW */
    margin: 0;              /* NEW */
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    width: 320px;
}


/* fix for issue with absolute position on firefox */

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .circle-outer p {
        left: -96px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -80px;
    }
}

/* some media queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    .circle-outer p {
        width: 200px;
        left: -36px;
    }
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        .circle-outer p {
            left: -36px;
        }
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .circle {
        margin: 50px 40px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 470px) {
    .circle {
        margin: 50px 20px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 373px) {
    .circle:nth-child(even) {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='features-section__features flex row'>
      <div class='circle circle-outer'>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people" class='img-responsive'>
          <p>This text should be below with ~ 11px margin.</p>
      </div>
      <div class='circle circle-inner'>
          <p>This text is happily set inside</p>
      </div>
      <div class='circle circle-outer'>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people" class='img-responsive'>
          <p>This text should be below with ~ 11px margin.</p>
      </div>
      <div class='circle circle-inner'>
          <p>This text is happily set inside.</p>
      </div>
      <div class='circle circle-outer'>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people" class='img-responsive'>
          <p>This text should be below with ~ 11px margin.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to not set the `top` or `bottom` at all, instead let it use its position set by the markup and then use `margin-top` to move it down.

I also removed the negative `left` settings in all the `.cirlce-outer p` rules (media query included) and instead added this once:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

With this the text will always be horizontally centered no matter the width you set.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2jc8ho9f/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
    background: #969898;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 980px;
    width: 90%;
}

.flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}


.row {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.img-responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.features-section__features {
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
}

.circle-inner {
    background-color: #8FCBE8;
}

.circle-inner p {
    color: #1E2D3B;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 54px;
    margin: 35px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}

.circle-outer {
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #8FCBE8;
    position: relative;
}

.circle-outer img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 116px;
    margin: 6px auto;
    width: 116px;
}

.circle-outer p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 48px;
    left: 50%;                         /*  changed  */
    transform: translateX(-50%);       /*  added  */
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 11px;                  /*  added  */
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    width: 320px;
}


/* some media queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    .circle-outer p {
        width: 200px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .circle {
        margin: 50px 40px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 470px) {
    .circle {
        margin: 50px 20px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 373px) {
    .circle:nth-child(even) {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
    <!-- NORMALIZE CSS -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css'>
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,500i,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

<div class='container'>
  <div class='features-section__features flex row'>
      <div class='circle circle-outer'>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people" class='img-responsive'>
          <p>This text should be below with ~ 11px margin.</p>
      </div>
      <div class='circle circle-inner'>
          <p>This text is happily set inside</p>
      </div>
      <div class='circle circle-outer'>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people" class='img-responsive'>
          <p>This text should be below with ~ 11px margin.</p>
      </div>
      <div class='circle circle-inner'>
          <p>This text is happily set inside.</p>
      </div>
      <div class='circle circle-outer'>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people" class='img-responsive'>
          <p>This text should be below with ~ 11px margin.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Good catch on the transform. That is simpler and helpful. The margin-top is a great solution as well. I'll check these out Monday on my project.